# 3D Animation Between Activity in Android

Tags: android, animation

How to create animation between two Activity look like As Screen shot in android[image]

Answer (score 7):

Search for `jazzyviewpager`. this is the  [link](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager) to the library. It has many cool animations to play with.

Comment: i want to apply annimation on image which inflates via view pager how can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's not **activity animation**, i believe it's **fragments animation** , activity animation is much more hard to implement smooth ,  [read here about fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4819665/849939)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to override Activity.overPendingtransition, and define transition animations in xml. Refer to [this](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343).